# Can chruby and chgems replace rvm's gemset?

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, chruby

I am currently using `rvm` on my development machine for switch between rubies (mainly 1.9.x and 1.8.7). Then I came across [`chruby`](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) and found the "Does not hook `cd`" feature attractive.

Can `chruby` + `chgems` replace `rmv`'s gemset feature?

Before:

```
$ rvm 1.8.7
```

will switch to ruby 1.8.7 with the 1.8.7 set of gems for my older rails projects. And:

```
$ rvm 1.9.3
```

will switch to ruby 1.9.3 with the 1.9.3 set of gems for my new rails projects.

How can that be achived by `chruby` and `chgems`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll take a run at this question since I use Chruby and Chgems. I am on Mac OS X, and I have chruby installed via Homebrew.

In my `.bashrc` file:

```
source /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh
chruby ruby-2.0.0-p195
```

The source line is part of [configuration](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby#configuration) for Chruby.

The second line sets a [default version](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby#default-ruby) of Ruby for my system (in my case Ruby 2.0.0). **Note:** As of Chruby 0.3.6 this belongs in `.bashrc` instead of `.bash_profile`.

In my `.bash_profile`:

```
source /usr/local/share/chruby/auto.sh
```

This line sets [Auto-switching](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby#auto-switching) feature in Chruby.

I still have some projects using Ruby 1.9.3 so for those apps I have a `.ruby-version` file in the root of the app. with one line `ruby-1.9.3`

---

When you cd into the directory for your app, type `chgems` and then you can bundle install and what not. You can confirm things are working by entering `gem env`

To make my life easier I added .bash_aliases for example:
`alias myapp='cd ~/Sites/myapp && chgems'`

---

I have been using these together for several months now and really like the combination and yes from what I can tell Chgems does a great job replicating the gemset feature of RVM. I highly recommend you read the docs for both [Chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) and [Chgems](https://github.com/postmodern/chgems) projects as this is all covered. In your case, you may not want to set a default Ruby and just use .ruby-version to set it for each app.

Comment: Updated my answer on June 24 to reflect changes resulting from the release of Chruby 0.3.6.

Comment: one can also use https://github.com/tonchis/gst it works better with chruby than chgems

Comment: Worth nothing: chgems has been deprecated in favor of [gem_home](https://github.com/postmodern/gem_home#readme).